# Filter Document Library on Catalog Item page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, catalog

For my company's Intranet I'm attempting to create a Product Catalog type site for our facility's equipment.  We have our equipment information in a *Product Catalog* site collection and then a *Publishing Portal* site collection that contains the search driven catalog item & category pages. This is all using the out-of-the-box features of SharePoint 2013 enterprise to set up friendly URLs, managed navigation, etc.

Another part of the publishing portal is a single document library that contains various engineering and maintenance documents for each piece of equipment.  I'd like to add a filtered document library web part to the catalog item page to allow users to add documents to this library right from the equipment's page.

Is this possible?  I've tried playing with the **Page Field Filter** and **Query String Filter**, but I can't figure out how to get them to work with the data provided by the **Catalog-Item Reuse** web parts.

I also tried just using `Content Search/Query web parts`, but they didn't seem to provide the ability to **upload** documents.

Comment: I noticed things were edited, and part of the review made it seem like the question may not be easy to read.  Should I change it?  I'm new to SharePoint, so maybe my terminology is all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't the ideal solution, but I was able to mostly achieve what I wanted by enabling the Content Organizer feature and adding that library to the Item page layout.

To sum it up, the Item page now contains

- Information about the item itself retrieved using Search from the Product Catalog
- Three Content Search sections for different types of documents stored in the Publishing Portal's documents library
- The document web part for the Content Organizer library that allows users to add documents.  These then get automatically moved to the main document library.

Hopefully in the future I'll come up with a way to allow users to edit documents from within this Item page, but for now, this solution will work.

Thanks for the help.